# Short overview of contents of list of tuples

Tags: python, debugging, tuples

Suppose a list of tuples, with contents of arbitrary length:

```
quotes = [('Shakespeare', 'Piccard', 'Allen'),
          ("To be, or not to be", "Earl Grey, 60 degrees", "I feel that life is divided into the horrible and the miserable. That's the two categories. The horrible are like, I don't know, terminal cases, you know, and blind people, crippled. I don't know how they get through life. It's amazing to me. And the miserable is everyone else. So you should be thankful that you're miserable, because that's very lucky, to be miserable."),
          ('beer', 'tea', 'vodka')
         ]
```

For debugging purposes, I would like to output the contents of the list:

```
print str(quotes)
```

However, I would like only the first N characters of any tuple value, I don't need the entire contents if it is long as in the third quote. **I know that I could write a function to iterate over the list and then to iterate over each tuple and slice the first N characters, but being Python I suspect that there is a simpler, shorter, more 'Pythonic' way.** Is there?

I am not looking for an XY solution for the current example, it is just an example to illustrate a point.

Comment: Looking for a list comprehension with a join, then?

Comment: What makes you think that such a function is not "Pythonic"? ["Readability counts."](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: Thank, Johnsyweb. I was actually considering quoting "Simple is better than complex." as the function would be four or five indent levels down. From my limited experience, in Python if it's over three indent levels down, then Guido already devised a better way.

Comment: True enough, but reducing the number of lines does not reduce the complexity. Flat is better than nested but that doesn't mean nested is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether this is pythonic enough, but still:

```
N = 10
map(lambda t: map(lambda s: s[:N], t), quotes)
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! That actually returns a list of lists, but I can work with that. Double thanks for introducing me to lambda functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try subclassing [`PrettyPrinter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter). Skimming through the source, it seems like the method you want to override is `format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)`:

```
import pprint

class TruncatingPrettyPrinter(pprint.PrettyPrinter):
    def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
        if isinstance(object, basestring):
            object = object[:72]+"..." # shorten strings to under 80 chars

        return pprint.PrettyPrinter.format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)

TruncatingPrettyPrinter().pprint(quotes)
```

This doesn't do *exactly* the same as `print str(quotes)` because `pprint` wraps and aligns structures. It also only truncates strings in the original object graph, instead of the resulting string representations of any other structures, but it gets the basic job (not having output too wide) done.

Comment: Thanks, millimoose. As I mentioned in the OP, I am looking for something a bit simpler, without writing a method / function. But this is a great example of overriding a method and will certainly come in handy at a latter state. Thank you very much!

Comment: @dotancohen My reasoning was more that "if you want to change how objects are formatted, there's one place that provides hooks for this mechanism". Unfortunately it's not built-in string formatting, which makes this approach not very "lightweight". So it's an option, but I'm aware it's possibly not the one you want.